# How to display values in list from mongodb using handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I need to display the mongodb output in listed format using handlebar file. I am using express js and handlebar templates

```
 { 
    "c_level" : "levelone",
    "c_group" : "groupone", 
 }

 { 
   "c_level" : "levelone",
   "c_group" : "grouptwo", 
 }

 { 
   "c_level" : "levelone",
   "c_group" : "groupthree", 
 }

 { 
   "c_level" : "leveltwo",
   "c_group" : "groupfour", 
 }

 { 
   "c_level" : "leveltwo",
   "c_group" : "groupfive", 
 }
```

Expected output

```
 Levelone
  - groupone
  - grouptwo
  - groupthree

leveltwo
  - groupfour
  - groupfive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash.groupBy

```
_.groupBy(data, "c_level");
```

then use the return value

to retrieve data in array form;

```
_.map(_.groupBy(data, "c_level"), function(items, level) {
  return {
    name: level,
    levels: _.map(items, "c_group")
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. I will try and get back